# TSQL OR Query Plan Hints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What kind of query hints can I use to improve the performance of an OR query.

Individually the two queries below run instantly and return 0 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM AuditInfo ai
WHERE (ai.AppointmentIdForChange = 60231)
and ai.objectname = 'dbo.Appointments'

SELECT * FROM AuditInfo ai
WHERE (ai.AppointmentIdForKey = 60231)
and ai.objectname = 'dbo.Appointments'
```

AuditInfo is a view.

However the following query runs forever (10+ minutes)

```
SELECT * FROM AuditInfo ai
WHERE (ai.AppointmentIdForKey= 60231 OR ai.AppointmentIdForChange = 60231)
and ai.objectname = 'dbo.Appointments'
```

How can I improve this? Are there query hints I can use?

In the estimated execution plan, I can see the individual queries use Key Lookups, whereas the query with the OR statement uses Index Seeks (which takes 74% of the cost).

UPDATE:

The AuditInfo view is defined as follows:

```
ALTER VIEW AuditInfo
AS
SELECT 
    ae.Id
    ,ae.AuditDateTime AS DateTime
    ,ae.ChangeTypeId
    ,ae.ObjectName
    ,aek.KeyName
    ,aek.KeyValue
    ,aek.KeyValueNumeric
    ,ae.UserId
    ,ae.HostName
    ,ae.ServerName
    ,aec.OldValue   
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 aecNewValue.OldValue AS Value
        FROM dbo.AuditEntries aeNewValue
        JOIN dbo.AuditEntryKeyValues aekNewValue ON aeNewValue.Id = aekNewValue.AuditEntryId AND aek.KeyName = aekNewValue.KeyName AND aek.KeyValueNumeric = aekNewValue.KeyValueNumeric
        JOIN dbo.AuditEntryChanges aecNewValue ON aeNewValue.Id = aecNewValue.AuditEntryId AND aec.ColumnName = aecNewValue.ColumnName
        WHERE aeNewValue.ChangeTypeId IN (0, 1) AND aeNewValue.AuditDateTime > ae.AuditDateTime AND aeNewValue.ObjectName = ae.ObjectName
        ORDER BY aeNewValue.AuditDateTime 
    ) AS NewValue
    ,appointmentForKey.AppointmentId AS AppointmentIdForKey, appointmentForChange.AppointmentId AS AppointmentIdForChange
FROM dbo.AuditEntries ae
JOIN dbo.AuditEntryKeyValues aek on ae.Id = aek.AuditEntryId
LEFT JOIN dbo.AuditEntryChanges aec on ae.Id = aec.AuditEntryId AND aec.ColumnName IN ('PatientId', 'AppointmentId')

-- Get AppointmentId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Appointments appointmentForKey ON aek.KeyName = 'AppointmentId' AND aek.KeyValueNumeric = appointmentForKey.AppointmentId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Appointments appointmentForChange ON aec.ColumnName = 'AppointmentId' AND aec.OldValueNumeric = appointmentForChange.AppointmentId

GROUP BY ae.Id, ae.AuditDateTime, ae.UserId, ae.ChangeTypeId, ae.ObjectName, ae.HostName, ae.ServerName, aek.KeyName, aek.KeyValue, aek.KeyValueNumeric, aec.OldValueNumeric, aec.OldValue, aec.ColumnName
,appointmentForKey.AppointmentId, appointmentForChange.AppointmentId
```

Comment: Are `AppointmentIdForKey`, `AppointmentIdForChange`, and `objectname` indexed?

Comment: They both correspond to indexed columns on two different tables.

Comment: What size table are we talking here?  I assume `AppointmentIdForChange` and `AppointmentIdForKey` are type `INT` and `objectname` is a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: @Jeff : Are those results consistent? Normally `Index Seek` should result in  faster execution time . Also, I wonder if you have `read_committed_snapshot` enabled for your db. From the table name I guess a lot of write activity on this table, and by default SQLServer writers block readers...

Comment: So they correspond to indexed columns on two different tables.  The question was are they indexed in AuditInfo?   Please post the actual query plans and table defintions.  A Key Lookup uses a clustered index.

Comment: Yes, they are consistent. AuditInfo is a view. I've updated the question to include it

Comment: Table sizes are very large (11M in dbo.AuditEntries and 41M in AuditEntryChanges)

Comment: No, they are not indexed in AuditInfo, the view, since the view is not indexable.

Comment: Audit info a view with joins is way different than the original question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. In my original question it says "AuditInfo is a view" right at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you ask for query hints but you could just run it as two queries with a union

```
SELECT * FROM AuditInfo ai
WHERE (ai.AppointmentIdForChange = 60231)
and ai.objectname = 'dbo.Appointments'
UNION
SELECT * FROM AuditInfo ai
WHERE (ai.AppointmentIdForKey = 60231)
and ai.objectname = 'dbo.Appointments'
```

As for will it perform tomorrow.
I will take a UNION over a JOIN or an OR for stability.
With a Union SQL does them one at a time and the query optimizer has less chance of getting stupid.

Comment: union performs the same as an OR. UNION ALL works fine, but doesn't produce the desired result. SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (... UNION ALL ...) works...but is somewhat verbose

Comment: So DISTINCT * FROM (... UNION ALL ...) works.  10 minutes down to fraction of a second but you are dismissing it because it is verbose?

Comment: Not dismissing it... I just want to figure out why it works and perhaps how I can force the desired execution plan which distinct plus union all seems to produce..the fact the the execution plan seems so unstable makes me worried about relying on this as a solution. .

Comment: Verbose or unstable what is the objection? Do you have ANY evidence this solution is unstable? You did not even realize a view with a join was pertinent.

Comment: There is no reason to be obnoxious. I pointed out that it's a view in my original post. It's relevant because I need a way of ensuring that SQL chooses a good execution plan both now and 2 weeks from now. The fact that there is such a big difference in performance leads me to think that as data is changed in the tables, SQL might suddenly choose a totally different (bad) execution plan two weeks from now. Do you have any evidence that SQL will consistently use the same execution plan given a DISTINCT + UNION ALL?

Comment: Worried the query plan may change could be said of any solution.  The query plan is not unstable.  You have one that consistently runs in minutes and one that runs in seconds.   An OR is not processed the same way as a UNION.  They will not have the same execution plan.  Given one runs in 10 minutes why would you want the same execution plan?

Comment: A query that performs today has a better chance of performing tomorrow than a query that does not perform today.